# How do I customise doughnut chart using chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to make chart.js like the following the example. 
When I hover the chart, the Element transform scale up
How can I make it?

example Link:http://bl.ocks.org/erichoco/raw/6694616/

Comment: Add your code..

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze the javascript code of your exemple.
I think that the function that doing this, is this one:

```
paths.enter()
    .append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', arc)
        .style('fill', function(d, i) {
            return color(i);
        })
        .style('stroke', '#FFFFFF')
        .on(eventObj)
```